# Using awk to split string with \n followed by ' and ,

Tags: linux, bash

If given the string `'1234␤',56789,` how can I use `awk` to split by the sequence `␤',`?  Here `␤` represents a literal newline character.

Right now I have,

```
echo $LINE | awk -F'\\\\n',' '{ print $1}'
```

The split doesn't happen with this. Any advice?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by _split_?  Ideally provide a non-trivial example of input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, I need \n' to be in the first field, and the part AFTER the comma to be in the next field. Basically, getting rid of the comma in the process.

Comment: I see.  Does this mean you do not want to split on any other comma characters elsewhere in the input?

Comment: ... an by '`\n`', do you mean the character '\' followed by the character `n`, or do you mean a newline?

Comment: I mean a newline, and yes I dont want to split on any other comma characters.

Comment: Do you have any additional lines of input that need to be processed?  The issue is that by default a newline is a RECORD separator in `awk`.  If I understand correctly, you are asking for this specific newline to not be treated as a RECORD separator.  Again I would encourage you to supply a non-trivial set of input data and expected behaviour.

Comment: Also don't keep changing the requirements, first you ask howto do this, and then what about if it is like this, and then what if it is like that?... You will not get any good answer, if not attract a down vote if you continue to go that route. My guess is you're trying to parse a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print all fields using the value of `-F`

```
echo "1234\n',56789," | awk -F "[',]+" -v ORS="" '{$1=$1}1'
```

```
line="1234\n',56789,"; echo "$line" | awk -F "[',]+" -v ORS="" '{$1=$1; print $0}'
```

Output

```
1234\n 56789
```

To print a specific field

```
echo "1234\n',56789," | awk -F "[',]+" -v ORS="" '{$1=$1; print $1}'
```

```
line="1234\n',56789,"; echo "$line" | awk -F "[',]+" -v ORS="" '{$1=$1; print $1}'
```

Output

```
1234\n
```

Comment: This leads to no output in the first field.

Comment: Still no output. jpmam1's method works, but I need it to splice a little differently as mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: It works on my side. I'll update and post an output.

Comment: It works when I use double quotes, but when I use single quotes(around the entire string), it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow what do you mean, do you have a different input string?

Comment: If I change the input string from "1234\n',56789," to '1234\n',56789,', and print out $1, $2 I only see 1234n.

Comment: Then the first non-empty field is `$2` and second non-empty field is `$3`

Comment: Okay, what if the input was 1234\n' ,56789,". How would you deal with the space?

Comment: add it to the `-F "[', ]+"` if you want the `"` quote `-F"[',\042 ]+"`

Comment: Okay, but this produces output without the ' after the \n, I need the ' to stay after the \n. Should I remove the ' from the []